# Content right aligned and horizontal scroll on IMac

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i was just working on **[THIS](http://codeandcode.co/demo/Express360/html/V1/)** site of mine and basically the problem is that on Mac-27 the site looks right aligned.

[image]

Now i tried all sorts of debugging , i tried taking off the JS and also tried taking off other components of the site to see if there is any problem , i alos tired removing the loader to see if that was cauing the issue , but nothing seems to be the problem , except in Mac-27 i have this issue I.E a horizontal scroll and right aligned content. Why is this happening , i am really clueless and have tried everything possible for debugging , but i am unable to zero down on why exactly this is happening.

P.S. To see the bug you will have to in your Dev tool , set the dimensions to 2560 x 1440 (Imac reslution) to see the bug.

**EDIT::** : Actually the bug is even more visible in 2100 * 1000 resolution in dev tool. The same bug has also been confirmed on a real iMac Device.

Comment: I can't recreate this in my Chrome dev tool at that resolution, still looks fine.

Comment: @Lee , `2100 * 1000` ? what resolution did you try ?

Comment: Both 2100x1000 and 2560x1440

Comment: I tried this on iMac 2k and in chrome emulator and  it works perfectly :(.